# how to sum three colums from three different table in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

i need all these three query in one query. plz help me regard this. I'm very new to laravel

```
    $month = date('m'); 

    $breakfast_cost=DB::table('breakfast_orders')
    ->join('breakfast_costs','breakfast_orders.date','=','breakfast_costs.date')
    ->where('breakfast_orders.user_id',$id)
    ->whereMonth('breakfast_orders.created_at',$month)
    ->sum('breakfast_costs.individual_cost');

    $lunch_cost=DB::table('lunch_orders')
    ->join('lunch_costs','lunch_orders.date','=','lunch_costs.date')
    ->where('lunch_orders.user_id',$id)
    ->whereMonth('lunch_orders.created_at',$month)
    ->sum('lunch_costs.individual_cost');

    $dinner_cost=DB::table('dinner_orders')
    ->join('dinner_costs','dinner_orders.date','=','dinner_costs.date')
    ->where('dinner_orders.user_id',$id)
    ->whereMonth('dinner_orders.created_at',$month)
    ->sum('dinner_costs.individual_cost');

    $total_cost=($breakfast_cost+$lunch_cost+$dinner_cost);
```

Comment: Is there any relation in these three queries ?

Comment: yes, same user has order for breakfast, lunch, dinner for a particular date.
no model is created . trying to do with query builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this if it helps you**

```
$total_cost = DB::table('users')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(breakfast_costs.individual_cost) as breakfast_sum, SUM(lunch_costs.individual_cost) as lunch_costs_sum, SUM(dinner_costs.individual_cost) as dinner_costs_sum')
    ->join('breakfast_orders','breakfast_orders.user_id','=','users.id')
    ->join('breakfast_costs','breakfast_orders.date','=','breakfast_costs.date')
    ->join('lunch_orders','lunch_orders.user_id','=','users.id')
    ->join('lunch_costs','lunch_orders.date','=','lunch_costs.date')
    ->join('dinner_orders','dinner_orders.user_id','=','users.id')
    ->join('dinner_costs','dinner_orders.date','=','dinner_costs.date')
    ->whereMonth('breakfast_orders.created_at',$month)
    ->whereMonth('lunch_orders.created_at',$month)
    ->whereMonth('dinner_orders.created_at',$month)
    ->where('users.id',$id)
    ->first();
return $total_cost;
```

*Also note that if you have any of these tables is optional, like it might have data for the user or might not, then you need to use `leftJoin` or `rightJoin` instead of `join` otherwise if any of them fails, it won't return exact record*

Comment: it worked, just one first bracket was missing. 
but the result is wrong.
your query brings out the sum of all orders, not individual's order

Comment: yeah it's simple not a problem check updated answer for the individual total, you know how this works, it just sum orders, sum lunch, sum breakfast and then sum all these three together.

Comment: Brother i would appreciate to have a conversation on zoom, but right now i am in office, you can understand. But you can write a detail scenario of your problem.